# Как объединить два List таким образом, чтобы

Tags: java, list, group-by

Как объединить, чтобы одинаковые элементы слились в один и получил на выходе

```
[productUuid=55d7cd69-7db0-43fc-8bc6-813db36f69f4, productName=Product740, amount=57], 
[productUuid=e6296ab4-9f94-4105-8212-b61555a04bef, productName=Product1065, amount=1],
[productUuid=e6296ab4-9f94-4105-8212-b61555a04bef, productName=Product560, amount=2]
```

первый List состоит из элементов:

```
[productUuid=55d7cd69-7db0-43fc-8bc6-813db36f69f4, productName=Product740, amount=47], 
[productUuid=e6296ab4-9f94-4105-8212-b61555a04bef, productName=Product1065, amount=1]
```

второй List состоит из элементов:

```
[productUuid=55d7cd69-7db0-43fc-8bc6-813db36f69f4, productName=Product740, amount=10], 
[productUuid=e6296ab4-9f94-4105-8212-b61555a04bef, productName=Product560, amount=2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Группировка по UUID и названию продукта
2. Суммирование по полю `amount`.

При условии, что существует список продуктов `List<Product>`, а класс `Product` имеет соответствующие геттеры для своих полей, указанный алгоритм удобно реализовать при помощи Stream API и коллектора `toMap` с функцией слияния:

```
List<Product> summaryByIdName = new ArrayList<>(
    Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p.getProductUuid() + "|" + p.getProductName(), // ключ по двум полям
        p -> p, // копируем текущее элемент Product
        (p1, p2) -> { // слияние при совпадении ключей
            p1.setAmount(p1.getAmount() + p2.getAmount()); // суммировать amount
            return p1;
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new // сохранить порядок вставки
    ))        // Map<String, Product>
    .values() // Collection<Product>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Goods> merged(List<Goods> fromFile, List<Goods> fromWeb) {

        List<Goods> raw = new ArrayList<>();
        raw.addAll(fromFile);
        raw.addAll(fromWeb);

        Map<String, Goods> toReturn = new HashMap<>();
        
        raw.forEach(rawProduct -> {
            if (toReturn.get(rawProduct.getProductUuid()) == null) {
                toReturn.put(rawProduct.getProductUuid(), rawProduct);
            }else {
                Goods toChange = toReturn.get(rawProduct.getProductUuid());
                int newAmount = toChange.getAmount() + rawProduct.getAmount();
                toReturn.get(rawProduct.getProductUuid()).setAmount(newAmount);
                
            }
        });

        return new ArrayList<>(toReturn.values());
    }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы.